# Mountain Lion, failed to install ruby on rails [ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-mountain-lion

I have tried different ways to install rails but never get it..
every time I type "gem install rails"..
it shows me `"ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."`

```
miketeki-iphone:~ Simon$ gem install rails
Failed to load /Users/Simon/.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML hash
Fetching: i18n-0.6.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.6.5
Fetching: multi_json-1.7.9.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_json-1.7.9
Fetching: tzinfo-0.3.37.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-0.3.37
Fetching: minitest-4.7.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitest-4.7.5
Fetching: atomic-1.1.13.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Simon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Simon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    --with-atomic_reference-dir
    --without-atomic_reference-dir
    --with-atomic_reference-include
    --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
    --with-atomic_reference-lib
    --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/Users/Simon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/Simon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/Simon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:817:in `try_run'
    from extconf.rb:24:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/atomic-1.1.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/atomic-1.1.13/ext/gem_make.out
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to check out this as well: http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: I think you should consider rbenv or rvm to install Ruby on Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

Either download and install 'command line tools' from apples developer download page: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ or just install xcode through App Store.. and try again.

And as mentioned by someone else in the comments, rbenv is a much better and easier way to manage your rubies on Mac OS X, so consider making the switch. to remove rvm from your system do: `rvm implode` and then restart your shell to make sure you are installing rbenv in a clean environment.

for detailed instructions on how to install a decent rails dev environment on mac take a look at the instructions i put together in a blog post here:

http://blog.parsalabs.com/blog/2013/08/27/setting-up-a-ruby-on-rails-4-development-environment-on-a-clean-mac-os-x-installation/

they worked for me, hope you will find them useful too.